# How can I add an executable to my path in a CircleCI job?

Tags: circleci

I am downloading and unzipping [binaryen](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/releases/tag/version_101) in a run step.

`- run: wget -c https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/releases/download/version_101/binaryen-version_101-x86_64-linux.tar.gz -O - | tar -xz -C /tmp/`

I am then updating the path in `$BASH_ENV`.

`- run: echo "export PATH=/tmp/binaryen-version_101/bin/wasm-opt:\${PATH}" >> $BASH_ENV`

However, I still get a command not found for `wasm-opt`.

How can I install the downloaded `wasm-opt` binary such that another run step can use it?

Comment: How about moving the file to an already known path ? (it is more of a quick fix than a battle tested solution)

Comment: Other than that maybe you could use the full path ?

Yes I only offer duck tape solutions :c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that the `PATH` variable should contain a list of directories. You added the actual binary itself to the path instead of the directory it resides in.

So for example, instead of `/tmp/binaryen-version_101/bin/wasm-opt` you want `/tmp/binaryen-version_101/bin/`. Also, after you add a directory to the `PATH` you won't be able to run those binaries until the next step.

Here's an example config I made:

```
version: 2.1
workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - build
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/base:stable
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: curl -sSL "https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/releases/download/version_101/binaryen-version_101-x86_64-linux.tar.gz" | tar -xz -C /tmp/
      - run: echo 'export PATH=/tmp/binaryen-version_101/bin/:${PATH}' >> $BASH_ENV
      - run: wasm-opt
```